# Golang ssh portforwarding : broken pipe error

Tags: mongodb, go, ssh, graphql, portforwarding

I am trying to connect to two remote mongodb servers using ssh port-forwarding in golang which are used by my graphql server for querying. The intermediary host for the two tunnels is same. So let's say the intermediary host is 123.45.678.678 and the two remote mongodb servers are 1.23.45.67 and 1.23.45.78, I create the tunnels like this,

```
conn, err := ssh.Dial("tcp", 123.45.678.678, config)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

remote1, err := conn.Dial("tcp", "1.23.45.67:27017")
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}


remote2, err := conn.Dial("tcp", "1.23.45.78:27017")
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

local1, err := net.Listen("tcp", "localhost:27018")
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

local2, err := net.Listen("tcp", "localhost:27019")
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

Now i forward traffic from local1 to remote1 and local2 to remote2 like this

```
go func() {
    for {
        l, err := local1.Accept()
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        go func() {
            _, err := io.Copy(l, remote1)
            if err != nil {
                panic(err)
            }
        }()
        go func() {
            _, err := io.Copy(remote1, l)
            if err != nil {
                panic(err)
            }
        }()
    }
}()
go func() {
    for {
        l, err := local2.Accept()
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        go func() {
            _, err := io.Copy(l, remote2)
            if err != nil {
                panic(err)
            }
        }()
        go func() {
            _, err := io.Copy(remote2, l)
            if err != nil {
                panic(err)
            }
        }()
    }
}()
```

And I create two mongo sessions using mgo.Dial and export these two sessions to the graphql whenever this function is called. For some queries ( not all queries, only some complex queries ) which need both the sessions, i see the write: broken pipe error

```
 panic: readfrom tcp 127.0.0.1:27019->127.0.0.1:53128: write tcp 127.0.0.1:27019->127.0.0.1:53128: write: broken pipe
```

When I debugged this, i figured out that this error occurs when the io.copy happens between l and remote2 in the code snippet above which i guess is due to the disconnection of remote2 tunnel.

The tcpdump showed that the intermediary host is sending the finish flag to the remote2 server after sometime which inturn is leading to the termination of the connection. I am wondering how I can resolve this.

Comment: Start by blocking during the copy. You only have one remote connection for each, so you can't accept more connections and start copying into the same tunnel. Don't panic on non-fatal errors. The only way you can break from your  copy goroutines is by an error, and in this case that causes you to crash.

Comment: I am very new to golang, so if u don't mind, could you explain what you mean by blocking and how it can be done here ?

Comment: It's more about the logic you're using to copy between connection. Your `for` loop dispatches 2 goroutines to copy in both directions, then waits to accept more connections. You don't want to do that, because if another connection comes in, you going to dispatch more goroutines to copy into the _same_ existing connection, which doesn't make any sense. You need to shutdown the remote connection when the client disconnects, because the connections to the mongo servers are in an unknown state.

Comment: So should I wait  for sometime before accepting new connections on local port ?

And also regarding closing connections, how do I close them after graphql job is done ? If I do defer remote2.Close() here, the connection closes before this function returns the created sessions to the graphql server.

Comment: I'm not sure of your intention here without more context, but a TCP proxy normally needs to create a new connection for each one it accepts. You can't patch random incoming connection onto existing ones, and "waiting for some time" before accepting again just delays the error. When you get a new connection, then dial a new one for the remote side. When one half of the connections closes, then close the other half.

Comment: The context is, I am trying to create a mongo session, one with each mongodb server. So my question is, after accepting a connection on port 27019 (on local machine) which is from my mongo process, should i stop accepting connections on that port (which i assume, means, bringing local.accept() out of that infinite For loop )?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151081/discussion-between-user1851006-and-jimb).